# Mvvm Prevent DataGrid change as it is not valid

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I currently work on a project in mvvm. So I have a DataGrid that only serves display and grid next that contains the entry zones for the addition / modification.

When I click on a line I use SelectedItem

```
  [RaisePropertyChanged]
    public virtual Ticket SelectedItem {get;set;}
```

An example when I click on a line

[SelectedItem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITpvf.png)

loads data in areas seizures.

and when I modify a captured area ...

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7M2b.png)

the data start to update in the DataSource of the grid.

what I would like is that the datagrid to be updated only when I finished my edition

xaml Code DataGrid

```
 <!-- DATAGRID -->
    <D:DataGridRecherche/>
    <D:DataGridTemplate  x:Name="Datagrid" MinWidth="250" Grid.Column="0"    Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"  ItemsSource="{Binding DataTickets}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <D:DataGridFirstColumn/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Tic_Id}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Width="Auto" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Tic_Date}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </D:DataGridTemplate>
    <!-- END DATAGRID -->
```

xaml code Edit Grid:

```
<Grid Name="Fiche"   Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Visibility="{Binding CurrentMode,  Converter={StaticResource FicheVisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource myFicheStyle}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Text="Fiche Tickets" Style="{StaticResource FicheLabelTitleStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>

        <!-- ID -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="ID :" Style="{StaticResource FicheLabelStyle}"/>
        <TextBox   Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                   IsEnabled="False" 
                   Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Tic_Id}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource FicheTextboxStyleNumber}"/>

        <!-- Date -->
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2"  Text="Date :" Style="{StaticResource FicheLabelStyle}"/>
        <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  
                 Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Tic_Date, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  
                 Style="{StaticResource FicheTextboxStyleText}" />


        <!--BUTTON FICHE -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="10">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button  Name="BtnAnnuler" Command="{Binding CurrentModeCommand}" CommandParameter="DEFAUT"  Style="{StaticResource FicheButtonAnnuler}"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"  Command="{Binding ValidatingCommand}"  Style="{StaticResource FicheButtonValider}" />
        </Grid>
        <!--END BUTTON FICHE -->
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` from your date TextBox binding:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  
         Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Tic_Date, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  
         Style="{StaticResource FicheTextboxStyleText}" />
```

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` triggers the binding to update the source as soon as you make a change.

Comment: the problem is that if I take it off I could not manage my mistakes in areas seizures

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I have to use UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged for manage errors so can't remove it, my problem is that I want the datagrid to be updated only after clicking the submit button

Comment: It is like I want to update it but, I don't want to update it. Maybe you should use a DatePicker control. It manages all the validation parts for you. Also, you get a nicer user interface for editing date.

Comment: I do not want the datagrid to be updated as my change / add has not been set. However I hope that in my areas of editing entries update the content for errors and for any areas saises (date, string, int ..).